# selenium says invalid url though it is not an invalid url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using openpyexcel and selenium in python and trying to open a website in my browser but I get that url is incorrect when the code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyexcel as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('something.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    website = str(sheet.cell(row, 1))
    src = str(sheet.cell(row, 2))

    

    browser.get(src)
```

but when I write the code like this it shows no error

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyexcel as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('something.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    website = str(sheet.cell(row, 1))
    #src = str(sheet.cell(row, 2))
    src = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/gmail/about/'
    

    browser.get(src)
```

both the urls are the same

the error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Malformed URL: URL constructor: <Cell 'Sheet1'.B2> is not a valid URL.

it is saying that the url in the cell B2 is invalid but when i tried the same url in the above code it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `src = str(sheet.cell(row, 2).value)`

`sheet.cell(row,2)` returns a cell object not string